# Graphics primitive generators

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, sprite

I'm looking for something that can generate primitives (e.g. rounded rectangles for dialog boxes etc) so I can load them into a DirectX textured Sprite.  Functionality is like [SPriG](http://www.ohloh.net/p/SPriG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty easy and there are 2 ways :

1) If you are using DirectX10+ use Direct2D.

2) Use GDI+ to draw them onto a texture.

Both are integrated with the system and do not need for any external library. Just pick and use.

As far as Direct2D, I don't know all the details, but I can assure you can do whatever you want with GDI+. (You generate them once, so you don't care about speed)

Comment: I'd like to use Direct2D, yes.  But it actually only works on Windows 7.

The GDI+ option isn't terribly bad, though.

Comment: As far as I know, Direct2D works fine on Vista too, if you installed the platform update.